# How to exit from adb dumpstate?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I'm running the following command from command prompt.

```
adb.exe -s localhost:5555 shell dumpstate
```

It does not exit after the completion.

I want the same result when running the following command

```
adb.exe -s localhost:5555 shell logcat -d
```

Is there any flag to pass with command to exit?